# Make an arbitrary slice type stringer method in Go

Tags: go

New to Golang. So I read about the stringer in the Go tour and I'm wondering is there any way to define a generic custom Stringer() for any type of slice? E.g.:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IntSlice []int

func (a IntSlice) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("len %d\tcap %d", len(a), cap(a))
}

func main() {
    a:=[40]int{}
    sa:=IntSlice(a[:])
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(a), "\t", unsafe.Sizeof(sa), " ", cap(sa))

    fmt.Println(sa)
}
```

Like this but without the type IntSlice definition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
type SliceStringer struct {
    Slice interface{}
}

func (ss SliceStringer) String() string {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(ss.Slice)
    return fmt.Sprintf("len %d\tcap %d", rv.Len(), rv.Cap())
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/jWnm9vCDFhq